# What is the origin of "nonchalance?"

Tags: etymology, antonyms

While reading a newspaper I saw the word [nonchalance](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=define:nonchalance&btnG=Search&meta=), looked up in dictionary, and dictionary says, it is a negative word meaning "indifference; carelessness; coolness." It looks like the opposite of *chalance*, but I was surprised to see there is no word as *chalance*. I am wondering if:

1. Isn't *nonchalance* made by adding *non* to *chalance* similar to nonsense?
2. What is the opposite of *nonchalance*? Can I write *nonnonchalance* just for the fun of it?

Comment: If you write nonnonchalance, I'm going to have to say nonnonnonchalance to give the opposite of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It comes from the French *nonchalant*, which means indifferent.

From [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nonchalance):

1670s, from Fr. nonchalant, prp. of nonchaloir "be indifferent to, have no concern for" (13c.), from non- "not" + chaloir "have concern for," ultimately from L. calere "be hot" (see calorie). French chaland "customer, client" is of the same origin.

Comment: hmm so in a very vague sense `chalant` is word opposite of `nonchalant` though it is not used

Comment: *Chalant* is not used, even in French. So I definitely would not use it in English either. But yes, if you ever find yourself in France in the Middle Ages, then you will be able to use the verb *chaloir*!

Comment: There is still *chaleur*, heat/warmth: if you're not prepared to work up a sweat, you're non-chalant. So far my little mnemonic.

Comment: Sure, *chaleur* is still used, but I guess it is more derived from the Latin *calor* (as are the Italian *calore*, *caldo* or the Spanish *caliente*). *Chalant*, would be the present participle of *chaloir*, and that's definitely a verb which I never heard used.

Comment: The only current use of chaloir is "Peu m'en chaut" (I couldn't care less") and it is old-fashioned.

Comment: @Alain: cool I didn't know that expression

Comment: @nico Spanish also has *calor* as a noun; *caliente* is an adjective.